# How can I convert dates that have extra characters in the middle

Tags: r

Some R date coercion fun.

The dates I'm trying to work with are organised as weird character strings. They have a "T" in the middle and a "Z" at the end, and include everything up to milliseconds, like this:

**2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z**

I've tried to convert them into strings using the as.Date function:

```
first_interaction_date <- as.Date(first_last_reading_date$first_interaction, format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ')
```

However, everything including and after the "T" gets cut off, like this:
**2018-01-01**.

I feel like there must be a really simple way to resolve this, but can't find it. I have both dplyr and stringr installed.

Many thanks!

Comment: maybe useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40938733/converting-character-to-timestamp-in-dataframe

Comment: Perfect, hadn't seen that! @user20650

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the package `anytime`:

```
library(anytime)

anytime(d1)
```

where `d1` is your date vector